# binding json into ui5 ObjectPageLayout dynamic

Tags: json, xml, sapui5

I have a JSON and want to create dynamic Sections and Subsections of an ObjectPageLayeout. My JSON looks like the following

```json
{
    "settings": {
      "Group1": [
        {
          "Group2": [
            {
              "Group3": [
                {
                  "value1": "asdf",
                  "value2": "5",
                  "value3": "2"
                },
                {
                  "value1": "jkl",
                  "value2": "2",
                  "value3": "0"
                }
              ],
              "Name2": "NameGr2"
            }
          ],
          "Name1": "NameGr1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

My data are given by ajax.

```js
var oConfig = oData.Payload.Value[0];

    this.models.mysettings = new util.JsonModel({
        modelData: oConfig.settings
    });
    this.models.mysettings.setDefaultBindingMode('TwoWay');
    oView.setModel(this.models.mysettings, 'mysettings');
```

Now I want to create an ObcectPageLayout in my xml view like

```xml
<m:Page>

    <ObjectPageLayout 
      enableLazyLoading="false"
      id="ObjectPageLayout">

      <headerTitle>
        <ObjectPageHeader objectTitle="Settings">
        </ObjectPageHeader>
      </headerTitle>

      <sections>

        <ObjectPageSection

          title="{mysettings>Name2}">

          <subSections>

            <ObjectPageSubSection
              title="{mysettings>value1}">

              <blocks>
                <l:Grid

                  defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12"

                  width="auto">

                  <l:content>

                    <forms:SimpleForm

                      minWidth="1024"
                      maxContainerCols="2"
                      editable="true"
                      layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                      labelSpanL="3"
                      labelSpanM="3"
                      emptySpanL="3"
                      emptySpanM="3"
                      columnsL="1"
                      columnsM="1"
                      class="editableForm">

                      <m:Label text="value2" />
                      <m:Input value="{mysettings>value2}"  />

                      <m:Label text="value3" />
                      <m:Input value="{mysettings>value3}"  />

                    </forms:SimpleForm>
                  </l:content>
                </l:Grid>
              </blocks>

            </ObjectPageSubSection>
          </subSections>
        </ObjectPageSection>
      </sections>

    </ObjectPageLayout>

  </m:Page>
```

Do you got any idea to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really clear what exactly you are trying to achieve or where you issue is, but here is a example how to display an ObjectPageLayout using your data: http://plnkr.co/edit/xXrMUggbvIkzQSMycVYa

What you seemed to miss is the aggregation binding of the sections and subsections:

```xml
<ObjectPageLayout sections="{mysettings>/settings/Group1/0/Group2}">
    <sections>
        <ObjectPageSection title="{mysettings>Name2}" subSections="{mysettings>Group3}">
            <subSections>
                <ObjectPageSubSection title="{mysettings>value1}">
```